# Magento CE 1.7.0.2 - Issue only occurs with caching enabled on footer.phtml

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I'm experiencing this problem with Magento when caching is enabled...

**Problem:**

Using the following in footer I can get the current CMS page title:

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getTitle();
```

^^ I have used this and other methods getting current URL in footer and experience same symptoms. With caching off it gets the current page no problem but with caching on it will get for example the page title for the shop then visiting other page shows that it is still shop.

**Here is a problem scenario with caching enabled:**

1. Visit homepage (http://devtest.eboost.com/).
2. Navigate to blog and scroll to the bottom so you can see footer. The hyperlinks for Powders, Shots, and some from Company should be different on homepage and all other pages. It behaves just fine with caching off. The links work fine in header.phtml and has the same logic.

Thing is with caching enabled it doesn't behave like this when in the header.phtml file so I'm confused. Do I need to do something special or maybe somehow take footer.phtml out of cache monitoring? I don't think removing it from cache monitoring would be wise because we have most of our JavaScript in this document.

I'm not sure what to do and very pressured to figure this out to make our client's website live.

Comment: What type of caching are you employing? EE FPC? TinyBrick LightSpeed? Or are you referring to the `block_html` cache?

Comment: Using Magento CE 1.7.0.2. We don't have any extensions for caching. It has compiling and caching enabled. All enabled on Cache Storage Management. The minute I turn caching off leaving compiling enabled it has the problem.

Comment: Haven't have much luck searching for a solution since I'm not quite sure what to look for specifically. Maybe tomorrow I'll come up with something. Thanks benmarks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: @benmarks 's Answer is miles better. Use that.

Try removing the footer from the cache. Try this - http://ken.edmonds-commerce.co.uk/magento/disable-footer-block-caching-in-magento/

Comment: The linked method really violates best practice and will be wiped out in an upgrade.

Comment: I applied the fix and it works. It wont be wiped from upgrade because I didn't modify the core file directly. I placed it in the local path. so instead of "Footer.php" being in "app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html" it is in "app/code/local/Mage/Page/Block/Html". This works for me now and will be keeping it this way for now.

Answer (score 2):

The application assumes that the footer block is not dynamic and it is therefore cached permanently. While this is a questionable decision for the core team to have made, you have two options: disable the cache or change the cache key to incorporate the dynamic parameters. Both can be done via class rewrite or via layout XML:

`block_html` cache has three "settings":

- `null` = never cache
- `false` = cache forever
- `int` = cache for this many seconds

In its constructor, `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Footer` sets its `cache_lifetime` property to `false` - hence its "permanently cached" behavior. Because this property is publicly accessible via the magic `setCacheLifetime()` method, it is possible to set its value from layout XML. Unfortunately there is no way to pass `null` as a value from layout XML as a string, however, it *is* possible to pass values via helpers. Therefore a helper method which returns `null` should work. There are some core helpers which do this; an example usage would be as follows (could be placed in your custom theme's *local.xml* which you may need to create):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <action method="setCacheLifetime" block="footer">
            <value helper="usa/convertMeasureWeight">
                <x>0</x>
                <x>0</x>
                <x>0</x>
            </value>
            <!--
                i.e.
                Mage_Page_Block_Html_Footer->setCacheLifetime(
                    Mage_Usa_Helper_Data::convertMeasureWeight(0,0,0)
                );
            -->
        </action>
    </default>
</layout>
```

That should work. However, this feels a bit hackish, so you could create your own helper class and just simply define a method to return `null` for the explicit purpose of setting this value.

Comment: Thanks Ben for your explanation however I did go with what James suggested via his linked solution except copied the core Footer.php to local folder so it wont be overwritten as I described in reply to his post. In the future I may go with your solution and will be sure to notify of results. Thanks so much!